# How to solve angular module got undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-controller, angular-module

I have four controllers in separate files

1. InvoiceCtrl
2. BillingCtrl
3. InvoicePaymentCtrl
4. InvoiceViewCtrl

2, 3, 4 have this **angular.module('invoice.controller',[])**

1 has this **angular.module('test',[])**

in my app.js i am using following code

```
angular.module('invoiceapp', ['invoice.controller','test','starter.services','ngDialog','angularMoment'])
```

Now whenever i try to change 1 same with 2,3,4

```
Argument 'InvoiceCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

Also i tried removing the [] in angular.module for each controller

Any one know how to solve this problem

Thanks in advance !

P.S each controller is in a separate file.

```
billing.controller.js
payment.controller.js
invoice.controller.js
view.controller.js

angular.module('invoice.controller', [])

.controller('BillingCtrl', function($scope,$http,Dialogs,Invoices){

    $scope.status = 'Billing OK!';

});

angular.module('invoice.controller', [])

.controller('InvoicePaymentCtrl', function($scope,$http,Dialogs,Invoices){

    $scope.status = 'Invoice Payment OK!';

});

angular.module('invoice.controller', [])

.controller('InvoiceCtrl', function($scope,$http,Dialogs,Invoices){

    $scope.status = 'Invoice OK!';

});

angular.module('invoice.controller', [])

.controller('InvoiceViewCtrl', function($scope,$http,Dialogs,Invoices){

    $scope.status = 'Invoice View OK!';

});
```

Comment: What does your InvoiceCtrl file look like?

Comment: Please, show me your code.

Comment: Just to confirm. You should use `angular.module('invoice.controller',[]).controller(...).controller(...)`, not `angular.module('invoice.controller',[]).controller('one'); angular.module('invoice.controller',[]).controller('two')...`.

Comment: thank you for response, i've edited the post and added my codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment you do this:

```
angular.module('invoice.controller', [])
```

You create a brand new module, you can leave out the subsequent module declarations and just use Controllers like this:

```
// app.js file
angular.module('invoice.controller', [])

// File #1
angular.module('invoice.controller')
.controller('BillingCtrl', function($scope,$http,Dialogs,Invoices){

    $scope.status = 'Billing OK!';

})

// File #2
angular.module('invoice.controller')
.controller('InvoicePaymentCtrl', function($scope,$http,Dialogs,Invoices){
$scope.status = 'Invoice Payment OK!';
})

// File #3
angular.module('invoice.controller')
.controller('InvoiceCtrl', function($scope,$http,Dialogs,Invoices){
    $scope.status = 'Invoice OK!';
}) 

// File #4
angular.module('invoice.controller')
.controller('InvoiceViewCtrl', function($scope,$http,Dialogs,Invoices){
    $scope.status = 'Invoice View OK!';
});
```

Notice the lack of the [] on the module? this is because using [] creates another instance of the application itself :)

Comment: thanks! but that was my previous format. now i find it hard to manage as the codes increase. i need to separate them into 4 different files.

Comment: OK ive changed the solution - make a note that every time you use [] in the module it creates a NEW module, leaving this out references the first app.module if named the same ans appends the controllers to it :) That caught me out a few times at first!

Comment: Hi sorry for late response, this is the error i'm getting now 
Module 'starter.controller' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument. i'm still figuring it out

Comment: Glad you sorted it! that one has stumped me before :)

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
angular.module('invoice.controller',[])
```

creates one new module.

You need to structure your code to create modules once, before using them. And then you attach controllers by getting a reference to the module created before:

```
var module = angular.module('invoice.controller');
```

I would do this:

- In app.js file I would do:

  angular.module('invoice.controller',[]);
  angular.module('test',[]);
- And then, in every other file, I would reference the module with

  var module = angular.module('invoice.controller');
  module.controller('InvoiceCtrl',...)